How to arbitrage options prices against prediction markets?
Suppose we have both put/call European-style options market and price prediction market on same underlying asset and same expiration date.
How can one arbitrage one against the other?
It seems that you can emulate option by buying bunch of prediction tokens, like 1 for [X,X+1) price range, 2 for [X+1,X+2) and so on. This does not seem practical, but this rule should give some kind of arbitrage possibility

Correct but completely impractical

@Dm63 Yes, surely seems impractical. But should not that kind of "emulation" brings some arbitrage opportunities by "approximation" ?
